# How do i use Mysql Alter Table in visual basic?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, vba

I want to create a button that will alter the table when users click it. In MySQL or PHPmyadmin i can use the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE TVShows DROP ShowID;
ALTER TABLE TVShows AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE TVShows ORDER BY Released Desc;
ALTER TABLE TVShows ADD ShowID int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
ALTER TABLE TVShows AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

How would i create a button in visual basic to execute this? I am new to programing so i thank you for any help.

Comment: Ok after some trial and errors i figured it out. here is the code i used if anyone needs it.

Comment: Dim query As String = "ALTER TABLE TVShows DROP ShowID; ALTER TABLE TVShows AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; ALTER TABLE TVShows ADD ShowID int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST; ALTER TABLE TVShows AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;"
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim sqlCmd As New MySqlCommand
        Dim Dreader As MySqlDataReader
        connection.Open()

        With sqlCmd
            .Connection = connection
            .CommandText = query
        End With
Dreader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()       Me.TVShowsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MycloudmediaDataSet.TVShows)

Comment: Rather than posting your code as an impossible-to-read comment, consider posting it as an answer instead, you're allowed to answer your own questions.